# How to keep a property value in django.values()?

Tags: python, django

I have my model as:

```
class Subs(models.Model):
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_column="order_date", null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def created_date(self):
        return self.created_at.strftime('%B %d %Y')
```

I want to get created_Date in my views.py

```
data = Subs.objects.values('somevalues','created_date')
```

It throws an error. How to access created_date so that I can use it here?

Comment: `data = Subs.objects.all().values_list('somevalues','created_date')`

Comment: i need the keys too as i use in it in template.

Comment: You can't use a model property in a values call. Do you actually need to use values, would iterating over a regular queryset where you could access the property work?

Comment: yes it works like that.

Comment: Don't use `.values()`: `.values()` are a problem exactly for that reason: it removes the model logic layer: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Answer (score 0):

As values didnot work i used for loop.
instead of doing this:

```
data = Subs.objects.values('somevalues','created_date')
```

I did this :

```
 newarr = [{'created_date': i.created_date} for i in Subs.objects.all()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your approach works, it's not best practice performance-wise. generally iterating whole `Model.objects.all()` is **a bad idea** because it loads all rows in memory.
In such cases you have several options:

- if you just need some simple python logic on your data (like formatting here) do this on the presentation layer (e.g. filter tags)
- if you need to apply some heavy business logic, it's better to have them in create/update time (e.g. overriding `.save()`) or have some cronjobs for it in off-peak time and save them in an extra column in DB.
- if your manipulation needs some DB layer query and depends on several columns or tables use `.annotate()` to add it into your queryset.